# AWK - How to subtitute one line with a pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I've this input file, I'd like to modify one line and keep the rest :

Input :

```
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Release||
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo1|0|
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo2|65#36|
Config.Ini|RESULT|Value|AAA#3#0#DOYO;1#1#TOTO#0##1###0#1###-1|
Config.Ini|RESULT|VERIF|0;162#3;3;;1;1;0;3;;;;####1#1;;;|
Config.Ini|PHONE|France|33|
Config.Ini|PHONE|Italy|39|
```

I'd like to use AWK to get this result :

```
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Release||
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo1|0|
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo2|65#36|
Config.Ini|RESULT|Value|AAA#1#0#DOYO;1#3#TOTO#0##1###0#1###-1|
Config.Ini|RESULT|VERIF|0;162#3;3;;1;1;0;3;;;;####1#1;;;|
Config.Ini|PHONE|France|33|
Config.Ini|PHONE|Italy|39|
```

The modification is very subtle. I focused on the only line I'd like to modify.

Input :

```
Config.Ini|RESULT|Value|AAA#3#0#DOYO;1#1#TOTO#0##1###0#1###-1|
```

Output desired :

```
Config.Ini|RESULT|Value|AAA#1#0#DOYO;1#3#TOTO#0##1###0#1###-1|
```

How could I get this result?

Comment: Match on first, second, third `|` separated fields. Do you want to the fourth field replaced or changed? If changed, how?

Comment: What can we use to find the line? Should we look for the exact string? A specific line number? All lines containing `DOYO`? Something else?

Comment: You're changing 3 to 1, and 1 to 3? Or setting the fifth and 16th characters to 1 and 3  regardless of their values? Or swapping the values of these characters? Or perhaps it's based on the pattern position within the string? What's the rule?

Comment: Could you describe the modification a bit more? Should the line be selected because it has `RESULT` in the 2nd pipe-delimited field and `Value` in the 3rd, or because it has `AAA` in the 4th field, or because it's the 4th line, or by some other criteria?  Should the first `3` be turned into `1` and that 2nd `1` be turned into `3`, or should the first and 4th number in that field be be swapped, or should the 5th and 16th characters be changed to `1` and `3` respectively?  What if those number were multi-digit, like 123 and 543?

Comment: Why does it have to be `awk`? Would `sed` not be acceptable?

Comment: No a swapping, a new value to replace the first 3 ... Indeed, I've choose a bad example maybe that why you thought of a swapping :-)

Comment: So how can we know which field of what line to swap?

Comment: please read all above comments asked you for clarification and [edit] your question and clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'#' -v OFS='#' '/RESULT\|Value/ {t=$2;$2=$5;$5=t}1' input.txt 
onfig.Ini|GENERAL|Release||
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo1|0|
Config.Ini|GENERAL|Foo2|65#36|
Config.Ini|RESULT|Value|AAA#1#0#DOYO;1#3#TOTO#0##1###0#1###-1|
Config.Ini|RESULT|VERIF|0;162#3;3;;1;1;0;3;;;;####1#1;;;|
Config.Ini|PHONE|France|33|
Config.Ini|PHONE|Italy|39|
```

Using `#` as the field separator for both input and output, swap fields 2 and 5 on lines that contain `RESULT|Value`.   The `|` has to be escaped with a backslash so that it is treated as a literal `|` rather than as extended-regexp alternation.